# Keeping only rows which are duplicated once only

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data set which looks like as follows:

```
A         B      C 
liver     5      RX
blood     9      DK 
liver     7      DK
intestine 5      RX
blood     3      DX
blood     1      DX
skin      2      RX
skin      2      DX
```

I want to keep only the duplicated (not triplicates or so on) entries based on `A`. Meaning if values in `A` are duplicate it should print the entire row.

The ideal output will look like:

```
A         B      C 
liver     5      RX
liver     7      DK
skin      2      RX
skin      2      DX
```

I tried using the following code with dplyr

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(n() >= 1)
```

Could someone please help me here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(A) %>%
 filter(n() == 2)

  A         B C    
  <chr> <int> <chr>
1 liver     5 RX   
2 liver     7 DK   
3 skin      2 RX   
4 skin      2 DX
```

Or a more verbose way to do the same:

```
df %>%
 add_count(A) %>%
 filter(n == 2) %>%
 select(-n)
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(A) %>%
 filter(max(row_number()) == 2)
```

Considering you may want duplicated cases based on "A" column that are otherwise unique:

```
df %>%
 group_by(A) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 filter(n() == 2)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: If this post helped, please accept it.